Proof that $f(x,t)$ can be written as $f(x-at)$ given certain condition.
Let's say I have a function $f:D \subset R^2\to R$ and $a = - \frac {{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}}} {\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}$ is true for every element of $D$, where $a$ is a real constant. How  can I demonstrate that $f(x,t) = f(x-at, 0)$
Also, if the reciprocal is true, how can I demonstrate that?
By the implicit function theorem I understand that $\frac{dx}{dt}=a$ but I don't know how to proceed from there

Is $f$ a function of one or two variables? Writing $f(x-at)$ seems to suggest the former.

This is badly written. Why have $f(x,t)=F(x,t)$ and then use $f$ for a general sungle-variable function? Confused notation can only lead to confused thinking. The implicit function theorem refers to a level set of the function, so thinking about the level sets might not be a bad idea.

Thanks for your comment, @TedShifrin. I removed $F(x,t)$ as it was not necessary and corrected the notation so that $f$ was a two-variable function.

You posted this same question a few hours ago before (presumably) deleting it.

The final thing should in fact be $f(x,t)=g(x-at)$ for some function $g$. Anyhow, as I suggested, what does the hypothesis tell you about the gradient vector of $f$ and level curves?

That question was wrongly formulated, so I figured to just delete it before anyone answers and post it when I have it ready. @Sambo

So is the expression '$f(x,t)=f(x−at,0)=g(x-at)$' sensical?, @TedShifrin. As a remark, I do need $g$ to not be an arbirtrary function, but rather related to $f$ by $f(x−at,0)=g(x-at)$

From your suggestion, I see that $x$ and $t$ are dependent in any level curve by $x-at=C_k$, where $C_k$ is a constant within the level curve $k$. Intuitively, that tells me that there exists a function $g$ such that $g(x-at)=f(x,y)$, but I don't know how to prove it. Also, $\nabla f=f_x(1, -a)$, which is independent of $t$. I feel like I'm getting closer to the answer but I still don't know how to continue.

Following from that, I would integrate the gradient to get the original function $\int f_x(1, -a) \cdot (dx, dt) = \int f_x, d(x-at)$. from where Idk how to proceed.
